# Reading Large collection from MySql

Tags: java, mysql

There is a table event_logs There are about 16 million entries in the table. Database is MySQL.

In application there is a need to read all rows one by one [specific to my application requirements]

Im just calculating retrieval speed

```
statement = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                        java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);   
statement.executeQuery("select * from test.event_logs");

long startTime = 0;
long endTime = 0;
int counter = 0;

while (resultSet.next()) {  

if (counter == 0){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();         
}

if(counter == 100000){
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();           
    long diff = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(diff);
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    System.out.println("diffMinutes" + " " + diffMinutes);
    counter = 0;        
}
counter++;
}
```

for 1st 100k records it took approx less than minute
for next 100k records it took approx one minute
for next 100k records it took approx 2 minutes
for next 100k records it took approx 11 minutes

after that I'm gettting this following exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 195 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 152,824 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:420)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7012)
    at com.google.io.InsertCampaignLogs.main(InsertCampaignLogs.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3629)
    ... 8 more
```

my questions

1.Why retrieving results time is increasing for the same number of records

2.Why I'm getting communication failed exception exception in the middle of the running query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might need to increase the transaction length or read the lines in junks. Read the first 10k, then the next 10k, each in a seperate statement.

Comment: I tried using seperate statement still I'm getting very slow query results after couple of minutes but at the beginning the query results speed is good.

Comment: Do you close all resources after the last usage of them?

Comment: yes I closed all the resources. I tried the way you told, but when I use limit 1000000,100000 , in this row number starts from 1000000 so its taking long time to get results